# Is there a way to automatically update an out-of-sync branch in githib?

Tags: github, githooks

We have an application where people fork the app and make PRs from their own branches of their forks. Since we have multiple teams making PRs, sometimes PRs get stuck in a situation where they have to keep updating their branch (whether locally and pushing, or by clicking the "Update Branch" button in their PR). Is there a way we can automatically start to update a PR's branch when the PR has already had the necessary approvals it needs for it to be merged, and it is out of date?

Comment: could probably do this via github actions on merge

Comment: Can github actions auto update an out of sync PR when it gets all necessary approvals?

Comment: you can write arbitrary code so sure